# how to fix java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Tags: java, weka, java-io, ioexception

I'm testing this class

```
     /**
     * Class to classify irises based on petal and sepal measurements.
     *
     * @author      James Howard <jh@jameshoward.us>
     */
    package us.jameshoward.iristypes;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Dictionary;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import weka.classifiers.Classifier;
import weka.core.Attribute;
import weka.core.FastVector;
import weka.core.Instance;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.SerializationHelper;

public class Iris {
    private Classifier classModel;
    private Instances dataModel;
    private String classModelFile = "/Irises/etc/iris.model";

    /**
     *  Class constructor.
     */
    public Iris() throws Exception {
        InputStream classModelStream;

        //  Create a stream object for the model file embedded
        //  within the JAR file.
        classModelStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(classModelFile);

        classModel = (Classifier)SerializationHelper.read(classModelStream) ;
    }

    /**
     *  Close the instance by setting both the model file string and
     *  the model object itself to null.  When the garbage collector
     *  runs, this should make clean up simpler.  However, the garbage
     *  collector is not called synchronously since that should be
     *  managed by the larger execution environment.
     */
    public void close() {
        classModel = null;
        classModelFile = null;
    }

    /**
     * Evaluate the model on the data provided by @param measures.
     * This returns a string with the species name.
     *
     * @param measures object with petal and sepal measurements
     * @return string with the species name
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public String classifySpecies(Dictionary<String, String> measures) throws Exception {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        FastVector dataClasses = new FastVector();
        FastVector dataAttribs = new FastVector();
        Attribute species;
        double values[] = new double[measures.size() + 1];
        int i = 0, maxIndex = 0;

        //  Assemble the potential species options.
        dataClasses.addElement("setosa");
        dataClasses.addElement("versicolor");
        dataClasses.addElement("virginica");
        species = new Attribute("species", dataClasses);

        //  Create the object to classify on.
        for (Enumeration<String> keys = measures.keys(); keys.hasMoreElements(); ) {
            String key = keys.nextElement();
            double val = Double.parseDouble(measures.get(key));         
            dataAttribs.addElement(new Attribute(key));
            values[i++] = val;
        }
        dataAttribs.addElement(species);
        dataModel = new Instances("classify", dataAttribs, 0);
        dataModel.setClass(species);
        dataModel.add(new Instance(1, values));
        dataModel.instance(0).setClassMissing();

        //  Find the class with the highest estimated likelihood

        double cl[] = classModel.distributionForInstance(dataModel.instance(0));
        for(i = 0; i < cl.length; i++)
            if(cl[i] > cl[maxIndex])
                maxIndex = i;

        return dataModel.classAttribute().value(maxIndex);
    }

}
```

when start initialising its instance from another class with

```
Iris irisModel = new Iris();
```

i got following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:159)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2320)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2333)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2804)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:802)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
    at weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(SerializationHelper.java:288)
    at us.jameshoward.iristypes.Iris.<init>(Iris.java:33)
    at us.jameshoward.iristypes.IrisDriver.main(IrisDriver.java:11)
```

I guess this error is case specific, by comparing with other posts, i still cant find out where it went wrong. in fact, this class was downloaded from IBMknowledge website, it supposes to be error-proof i guess.
anyone knows how to fix this? 
thanks

Comment: I'm almost sure the file is not there. Verify that the model file is in the right place...

Comment: The iris.model file is a file created by deserializing a java object?

Comment: file is there, i double checked, iris.model is a file created by Weka which is a java program, but im not sure if it's created by deserializing a java object though

Comment: i downloaded from http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/bd-javaweka/   just in case someone wanna try

Comment: Well, the first few relevant hits for "BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen stream closed" all refer to some kind of a file existence problem, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124544/strange-ioexception-when-buffering-inputstream-in-java).

Just for reference, could you add some kind of a folder structure, how the files are laid out?

Comment: What if the file exists but is empty?

Comment: i just tested file, im sure file is not empty cuz i replaced with another newly generated file  and i got same error.

Comment: Can you provide (a portion) of the files content?

Comment: ¨Ìsr!weka.classifiers.trees.RandomTree{˝◊yÛ. Zm_AllowUnclassifiedInstancesIm_KValueI
m_MaxDepthDm_MinNumI
m_NumFoldsIm_randomSeedLm_InfotLweka/core/Instances;Lm_Treet(Lweka/classifiers/trees/RandomTree$Tree;Lm_zeroRtLweka/classifiers/Classifier;xrweka.classifiers.ClassifierZ>Ñ!Ω&#MZm_Debugxp?srweka.core.Instancesˇªì4e©§IattIdx4RandomizationIm_ClassIndexIm_Lines[attIdxOrigValuest[DLm_AttributestLweka/core/FastVector;Lm_Instancesq~Lm_RelationNametLjava/lang/String;xpˇˇˇˇpsrweka.core.FastVector·’≤

Comment: Just downloaded the package, file is there and @k5_ is definitely on the right tracks - Which version of Java do you use?

Comment: java 1.8, you think it's related to java version?

Comment: Did you try to use SerializationHelper.readAll ?

Comment: As the file seems to be a serialized Java object, the Java version can play a role... If you can create that file yourself, you could try creating it using the same Java version as the one you use with the class...

Comment: changed java version seems working, can you edit your answer?@ppeterka